# How to programmatically access and manipulate Discussion item and replies?

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, permissions, discussion-board

How to access and manipulate Discussion item and replies?

I have a discussion board that has a check box, based on the input I switch the permissions of that discussion post for a specific user (from Read to Contrib and vise versa) via a List Item event receiver.

The issue is whenever I switch around the permissions for a certain user, that user looses the view rights to the replies of the discussion post. The user can only see his own replies.

How can propagate my permission changes to all the replies of that thread? And maintain the view rights through out.?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you have a checkbox on the root discussion item that changes the toggles the permissions for the thread, which you are triggering via an event receiver.  It sounds to me like you would update your existing event receiver to evaluate its parent item.

Ultimately this sounds like a bit of a complex scenario that will be difficult to maintain.

Comment: Yes @Mike-Oryszak..
What I basically want is a check box to enable or disable the ability to reply for a set of people.